# How do I get ownership of a &[u8] without cloning?

Tags: rust, lifetime

Polling for a series of events, the need to discard duplicates arises.

Events can be serialised into bytes with `.as_bytes()`, which can then be placed into a cache so that they can be skipped:

```rust
let mut cache = LruCache::new(10_000);

loop {    
    let events: Vec<Evt> = get_events().
        .into_iter()
        .filter_map(|evt| {
            let key = evt.as_bytes().to_owned();
    
            if cache.contains(&key) {
                return None;
            }
            cache.put(key);
            Some(Event::from_bytes(&evt.as_bytes()).unwrap())
        })
        .collect();
    
    // ... use `events`
}
```

In a closure, we need to `move` the events out of it so that their lifetime lasts as much as the `cache` does.

One way to do it, is to call `.to_owned()` on them. However, for [u8] values, this is implemented as a `.to_vec()`, which copies them instead of moving them, incurring into additional overhead.

Apparently `[T]` slices implement an `.into_vec()` method, but this is not available on `&[u8]` references:

```
error[E0599]: no method named `into_vec` found for reference `&[u8]` in the current scope
  --> src/main.rs:55:41
   |
55 |                 let key = evt.as_bytes().into_vec();
   |                                          ^^^^^^^^^^ help: there is an associated function with a similar name: `to_vec`
```

How can `&[u8]` be move out of the closure, without incurring into the additional overhead cost associated with copying it?

Comment: getting owner ship of something borrowed.... don't make any sense to me [mcve]

Comment: Sounds more like you want shared ownership, in which case you can store an `Rc<Event>` (or `Rc<(Event, &[u8])>` if `as_bytes()` is expensive) in your cache.

Comment: @Stargateur as in please let this thing live longer, but don't copy it, just let it live longer

Comment: How does `as_bytes` return a reference rather than something owned?

Comment: @SolomonUcko yeah unfortunately I don't control the evt producer as it's an external library. There's the option to either own the whole Event (not `Hash`able) or to get a reference to the underlying bytes.

Comment: How exactl do you "use" events? Can your cache hold _references_ to the data in events?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As was mentioned in the comments, you can't own something that is borrowed. Imagine borrowing your neighbor's car, and trying to keep it... that won't go over well.

A `u8` impls [`Copy`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Copy.html), which means that creating a new instance of it is a simple bit-wise copy, which will *not* incur any additional overhead, like you said you are worried about.

The Rust compiler is really impressive, it is telling you the best solution to try to accomplish what it thinks you want to do, by using `to_vec()` to get an owned Vec.

Comment: `to_vec()` allocates and copies. It _does_ add overhead, and can be a non-negligible overhead. The fact that `u8` impls `Copy` is not relevant at all here.

Comment: Copying 1 u8 is O(1). Copying n u8's is O(n).

Answer (score 0):

You need to either make the lifetime of the reference long enough, use an `Rc`/`Arc`/similar, or copy the data to a `Vec`. See also [`std::collections::HashSet`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashSet.html) and [`itertools::Itertools:: unique_by`](https://docs.rs/itertools/latest/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.unique_by).

Comment: any way to do the first without having control over the value returned by `.as_bytes()`? `getEvents()` is from an external lib...